# Why is data not being inserted in the database in the following code?

Tags: java, android-studio

I am a newbie in android programming. This is what I have learned from tutorials but I am not able to understand why the app does not store data which i insert.  This is my code but whenever I run the application it says data not inserted.

**This is DataBaseHelper class**

```
package com.dutt.rishabh.android.sqlite.contacts;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by Rishabh on 06-07-2016.
*/

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME="contacts.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME="student_contacts";
public static final String id="ID";
public static final String COL_1="NAME";
public static final String COL_2="PHONE NUMBER";
public static  final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query="create table "+TABLE_NAME+"("+id+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT,"+COL_1+" TEXT NOT NULL,"+COL_2+" TEXT NOT NULL"+")";
    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("Drop table if exists "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
public boolean addData(String name,String num ){
    SQLiteDatabase myDb=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues content=new ContentValues();
    content.put("NAME",name);
    content.put("PHONE NUMBER",num);
    long result=myDb.insert(TABLE_NAME,null ,content);
    if(result==-1){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }



}
public Cursor viewData(){
    SQLiteDatabase myDb=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cr= myDb.rawQuery("Select * from   "+DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME,null);
    return cr;
}
}

**This is MainActivity class**

package com.dutt.rishabh.android.sqlite.contacts;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button add, view;
    EditText name, num;
    Contact contact;
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper= new DatabaseHelper(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num);
    view = (Button) findViewById(R.id.view);
    //contact = new Contact(name.getText().toString(), num.getText().toString());

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            boolean m = dbHelper.addData(name.getText().toString(),num.getText().toString());
            if (m) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Inserted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data not Inserted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Cursor res = dbHelper.viewData();
            if (res.getCount() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Data Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            while (res.moveToNext()) {
                sb.append("ID: " + res.getString(0) + "\n");
                sb.append("NAME: " + res.getString(1) + "\n");
                sb.append("PHONE NUMBER: " + res.getString(2) + "\n\n");
            }
            showData("Details",sb.toString());
        }
    });
}

public void showData(String title, String mess) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(mess);
    builder.show();
}
```

}

Comment: Why your column name `public static final String COL_2="PHONE NUMBER"` contains space? Use "_" like this: PHONE_NUMBER.
Here too: `content.put("PHONE NUMBER",num);`

Comment: Thanks now it's working